# Get SQL creating new table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, orm

I use Entity Framework 6.0.2 as ORM, I create new type

```
public class DataSourceImportReport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ImportedCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }
    public DataSource DataSource { get; set; }
}
```

and I added mapping to `OnModelCreating` method

```
ModelBuilder
    .Entity<DataSourceImportReport>()
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("DataSourceImportReports", dataSourceSchemaName));
```

I want to get the SQL statements generated by EF to add proper table in database.

How can I do this?

Comment: i'm not really clear about your question. why do you need sql statements to create a table, if you setup everything correct ef creates the table on your first call to database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ExecuteCommand()` method to create the table yourself e.g.

```
db.ExecuteCommand("CREATE TABLE...");
```

Comment: EF will create table in database, I want to get this sql, which creating table

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in consol package manager and generate database :

```
PM> enable-migrations

PM> add-migration a

PM> update-database -verbose
```

you must set connectionstring in startup project.

Comment: That said, the table will be anemic. No conditions, no indices, no advanced options. Ok, table advanved options are rarely used, but heck, unique constraints and indices are sort of baseline.

Comment: see this link ; http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx

Comment: yes, as I said - anemic. Ever seen a filtered index? An index that is NOT realted to a relation but used to *cough* speed up a query? A table that is partitioned? Or calculated fields.... that have an index to speed up querie? As I said - anemic. As primitive as it gets, smallest common denominator, good enough for everyone never having read a book about SQL.

Comment: ok..I think you should read a book about entityframework and orm concept.

Comment: hardly. I wrote something like that ages ago. Point is the question is automatic generation of the database and any ORM I know of makes a CRAPPY job of that. And no, contrary to what some ppl think, an ORM will not make the need for those features go away. Obviously you never worked on a database project where people take a day to tune the migration scripts of peddle around with some of the features of sql server that are useless for small data. Leave it at that. Migrations are terrible for real complex database work.